# Can Derby database store millions of records

Tags: derby

Am working on a library management system and am trying to use and embedded database. Can Derby store thousands and probably millions of records.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that this is an appropriate stackoverflow question. However, I have used Derby as a local database for an offline application which did partial synchronisation with an Oracle database since the mid noughties and yes it can handle millions of records.

Comment: It's Open Source and it's free, so one approach is just to download it from http://db.apache.org/derby and try it! Write some benchmarks, load in some data, see what you can learn!